# Error ninject the type "T" must be convertable to "T"in order to use it as a parameter "T" in generic method

Tags: c#, ninject

I have this code

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{

    private IKernel ninjectKernel;
    public NinjectControllerFactory()
    {
        ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
        RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null
            ? null
            : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        ninjectKernel
            .Bind<ICollection>().
            To<ListOfProcess.ConnectionLogic.ConnectionLogic>();
    }
}
```

and have next error in last line:
    The type "T" must be convertable to "T"in order to use it as a parameter "T" in      generic method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `ListOfProcess.ConnectionLogic.ConnectionLogic` does not implement `ICollection`.

(in case it's a nested type: not `ListOfProcess`, not `ListOfProcess.ConnectionLogic` but `ListOfProcess.ConnectionLogic.ConnectionLogic` is the one which does not implement `ICollection`)